# (fullcalendar) Calendar re-renders to the initial setttings, when the data gets fetched the first time

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

in react, I have used react-fullcalendar, but when I fetch data from api for the first time when the the calendar mounts, it gets re-render on the initial setting with the event array that are coming from api. (e.g) when the calendar loads and I change the defualt calendar from week to month and change the filter to load data, it gets re-render to the week calendar

> https://admin-dot-konav2-dev.wl.r.appspot.com/login
>
> email: m.ashir@sparkai.ca
> password: Ethera2021!

Here is my code for Calendar.

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
  useRef,
  useState,
  lazy,
  memo,
  Fragment
} from 'react'
import { getDurations } from '@utils'

// ** Reactstrap
import { Card, CardBody, Label } from 'reactstrap'

// ** Calendar Plugins
import Flatpickr from 'react-flatpickr'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import ScrollGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/scrollgrid'
import resourceTimeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid'

// ** Third Party Components
import moment from 'moment'
import * as Icon from 'react-feather'

// ** Hooks
import useMediaQuery from '@src/utility/hooks/useMediaQuery'

// ** Custom Components
import SelectField from '@select'
const BookingUpdate = lazy(() =>
  import(
    '../../components/screen.components/bookings/booking-modal/BookingUpdate'
  )
)
const calendarsColor = lazy(() =>
  import('@ScreenComponent/calendar.screen/constants')
)
const DurationComponent = lazy(() =>
  import('@ScreenComponent/calendar.screen/DurationComponent')
)
const ViewComponent = lazy(() =>
  import('@ScreenComponent/calendar.screen/ViewComponent')
)

function Calendar() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const calendarRef = useRef(null)
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(max-width: 600px)')
  const largeScreen = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 1350px)')
  const extraLargeScreen = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 1500px)')

// ** Selectors
  const {
    success,
    loading,
    getBooking,
    getAllBookings,
    bookingPending,
    updatePending
  } = useSelector((state) => state.booking)
  const roomsPending = useSelector((state) => state.rooms.loading)
  const getAllRooms = useSelector((state) => state.rooms.getAllRooms?.roomsList)
  const locationsPending = useSelector(
    (state) => state.locations.getAllLocations?.loading
  )
  const getAllLocations = useSelector(
    (state) => state.locations.getAllLocations?.locationsList
  )

  const rows = getAllBookings?.bookingsList
  const rowsFiltered = rows.filter((row) => row.status === 1)

    // ** States
    const [room, setRoom] = useState()
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState('')
    const [location, setLocation] = useState()
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState('')
    const [roomsList, setRoomsList] = useState([])
    const [view, setView] = useState('timeGridWeek')
    const [eventsList, setEventsList] = useState([])
    const [calendarApi, setCalendarApi] = useState(null)
    const [locationsList, setLocationsList] = useState([])
    const [addSidebarOpen, setAddSidebarOpen] = useState(false)
    const [allRoomsDayGrid, setAllRoomsDayGrid] = useState(true)

  // ** Referencing Calendar
      useEffect(() => {
        if (calendarApi === null) {
          setCalendarApi(calendarRef.current.getApi())
        }
      }, [calendarApi])
    
      // ** Getting Bookings
      useEffect(() => {
        if (location?.value) {
          dispatch(
            getAllBookingsAction({
              offset: 0,
              limit: 100,
              startDate,
              endDate,
              location: location?.value,
              room: view === 'resourceTimeGridDay' ? '' : room?.value,
              callback: () => setEventsList([])
              // callback: () => {}
            })
          )
        }
      }, [endDate, location, room, success, dispatch, view])
    
      // ** Getting Locations
      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getAllLocationsAction())
      }, [dispatch])

     // ** Getting Rooms
    useEffect(() => {
      if (location?.value) {
        dispatch(getAllRoomsAction({ id: location?.value }))
      }
    }, [location?.value, dispatch])

  // ** Creating Locations List
  const arrLocations = useMemo(() => {
   if (!getAllLocations) {
     return []
   }

    const locations = []
    getAllLocations.forEach((item) => {
      locations.push({
        text: item?.name,
        value: item.id
      })
    })
    return locations
  }, [getAllLocations])

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocation(arrLocations[0])
    setLocationsList(arrLocations)
  }, [arrLocations])

 // ** Create Rooms lists
   const arrRooms = useMemo(() => {
     if (!getAllRooms) {
       return []
     }

     const rooms = []
     getAllRooms.forEach((item) => {
       rooms.push({
         text: item?.name,
         value: item.id
       })
     })
     return rooms
   }, [getAllRooms])

   useEffect(() => {
     setRoomsList(arrRooms)
   }, [arrRooms])

     // ** Rooms Resources
     const resources = useMemo(() => {
       return roomsList.map((room) => {
         return { id: room.value, title: room.text }
       })
       // .filter((_, index) => index !== 0)
     }, [roomsList])

      // ** Function to handle sidebar visibility
       const handleAddAppointmentSidebar = (id) => {
         setAddSidebarOpen(!addSidebarOpen)
         if (id && addSidebarOpen === false) {
           dispatch(getBookingByIdAction(id))
         }
       }

       // ** Date Picker
        const onDateChangeHandler = (dates) => {
          if (dates.length === 1) {
            setStartDate(dates[0])
            calendarRef.current.getApi().gotoDate(new Date(dates[0]))
          }
          if (dates.length === 2) {
            setStartDate(dates[0])
            setEndDate(dates[1])
            calendarRef.current.getApi().gotoDate(new Date(dates[1]))
          }
        }

  // ** Function to handle filters
    const onChangeHandler = (name, value) => {
      if (name === 'location') setLocation(value)
      if (name === 'room') setRoom(value)
    }

  // ** Events
    const memoizedEvents = useMemo(() => {
      let events = []
      const viewComp = view === 'resourceTimeGridDay' || room?.value
  
      if (rowsFiltered.length > 0 && viewComp) {
        events = rowsFiltered.map((row) => {
          // const end_time_h = parseInt(row?.end_time.split(':')[0]) + 1
          // const end_time_m = row?.end_time.split(':')[1]
          // const end_time = `${end_time_h}:${end_time_m}`
  
          return {
            allDay: false,
            url: '',
            start: `${row?.start_date__date}T${row?.start_time}`,
            end: `${row?.start_date__date}T${row?.end_time}`,
            title: `${row?.provider__first_name} ${row?.provider__last_name}`,
            resourceId: row?.room__id,
            extendedProps: {
              id: row?.id,
              date: row?.start_date__date,
              calendar: 'Ethera OC',
              img: row?.provider__avatar,
              end_time: row?.appointments__end_time || '--',
              start_time: row?.appointments__start_time || '--',
              duration: `${row?.duration / 3600} hours`
            }
          }
        })
      }
  
      return events
    }, [rows, view])

  

  const memoizedDurationEvents = useMemo(() => {
    const durationEvents = []
    const durComp = view === 'timeGridWeek' || view === 'dayGridMonth'

    if (rowsFiltered.length > 0 && !room?.value && durComp) {
      const durations = getDurations(rowsFiltered)

      durations.map((durationObj, index) => {
        const arr = Object.entries(durationObj).map(([key, value]) => ({
          date: key,
          duration: value
        }))

        arr.forEach((item) => {
          let sum = 0
          const duration = item.duration
          duration.map(function (dur) {
            sum += parseInt(dur)
          })

          durationEvents.push({
            allDay: true,
            url: '',
            id: `${index}`,
            start: `${arr[0].date}`,
            end: `${arr[0].date}`,
            title: `${sum / 3600}`,
            extendsProps: {
              start: `${arr[0].date}`,
              end: `${arr[0].date}`,
              calendar: 'Ethera OC'
            }
          })
        })
      })
    }

    return durationEvents
  }, [rows, view])

    const EventRenderer = (arg) => {
      if (room?.value) {
        return <ViewComponent calendarEvent={arg?.arg?.event} view={view} />
      } else {
        return <DurationComponent calendarEvent={arg?.arg?.event} />
      }
    }

  // ** Reset Bookings
    useEffect(() => {
      return () => {
        dispatch(resetBookings())
      }
    }, [])

  const calendarOptions = {
      resources,
      navLinks: true,
      dayMaxEvents: 1,
      editable: false,
      // dragScroll: true,
      ref: calendarRef,
      selectable: true,
      nowIndicator: true,
      eventOverlap: false,
      stickyHeaderDates: true,
      initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
      stickyFooterScrollbar: true,
      // slotMinTime: '08:00:00',
      slotDuration: '01:00:00',
      snapDuration: '01:00:00',
      // eventResizableFromStart: true,
      // timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
      schedulerLicenseKey: '0127232346-fcs-1571929973',
      events:
        view === 'resourceTimeGridDay' || room?.value
          ? memoizedEvents
          : view === 'timeGridWeek' || view === 'dayGridMonth' || !room?.value
          ? memoizedDurationEvents
          : [],

      dayHeaderFormat: {
        weekday: 'long',

        omitCommas: true
      },
      plugins: [
        interactionPlugin,
        ScrollGridPlugin,
        resourceTimeGridPlugin,
        dayGridPlugin,
        timeGridPlugin
      ],
      eventClassNames({ event: calendarEvent }) {
        const colorName =
          calendarsColor[calendarEvent?.extendedProps?.calendar] || 'admin'
        return [`bg-light-${colorName}`]
      },

      headerToolbar: {
        left: (() => {
          if (isMobile) {
            return 'title, prev, next'
          } else {
            return 'title, prev, next, resourceTimeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth'
          }
        })(),
        center: (() => {
          if (isMobile) {
            return 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,resourceTimeGridDay'
          } else return ''
        })(),
        right: 'venueSelect'
      },

      views: {
        resourceTimeGridDay: {
          type: 'resourceTimeGrid',
          duration: { days: 1 },
          buttonText: 'Day',
          dayMinWidth: 270,
          slotLabelFormat: {
            hour: 'numeric',
            minute: '2-digit'
          },
          allDaySlot: false,
          eventContent: (arg) => {
            return (
              <ViewComponent
                calendarEvent={arg.event}
                view={view === 'dayGridMonth'}
              />
            )
          },
          viewDidMount: (args) => {
            console.log('resourceTimeGrid test')
            setView(`${args?.view?.type}`)
            setAllRoomsDayGrid(false)
            // setRoom(null)
          },
          eventClick: (arg) => {
            console.log('Event Click  : ', arg)
            handleAddAppointmentSidebar(arg.event._def?.extendedProps?.id)
          }
        },
        timeGridWeek: {
          type: 'timeGrid',
          duration: { weeks: 1 },
          buttonText: 'Week',
          dayMinWidth: 170,
          dayHeaderFormat: {
            weekday: 'long',
            omitCommas: true,
            day: 'numeric'
          },
          slotLabelFormat: {
            hour: 'numeric',
            minute: '2-digit',
            hourCycle: 'h12',
            timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
          },
          eventContent: (arg) => {
            return <EventRenderer arg={arg} />
          },
          viewDidMount: (args) => {
            console.log('timeGrid test')
            setAllRoomsDayGrid(true)
            setView(`${args?.view?.type}`)
          },
          eventClick: (arg) => {
            if (room?.value) {
              console.log('Event Click  : ', arg)
              handleAddAppointmentSidebar(arg.event._def?.extendedProps?.id)
            }
          }
        },
        dayGridMonth: {
          type: 'dayGridMonth',
          duration: { months: 1 },
          buttonText: 'Month',
          dayMinWidth: 160,
          eventContent: (arg) => {
            return <EventRenderer arg={arg} />
          },
          viewDidMount: (args) => {
            console.log('dayGridMonth test')
            setAllRoomsDayGrid(true)
            setView(`${args?.view?.type}`)
          },
          eventClick: (arg) => {
            if (room?.value) {
              console.log('Event Click  : ', arg)
              handleAddAppointmentSidebar(arg.event._def?.extendedProps?.id)
            }
          }
        }
      },
      customButtons: {}
      //   businessHours: [ // Optional - the hours when the business is open
      //   {
      //     daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // Monday - Friday
      //     startTime: '08:00',
      //     endTime: '17:00'
      //   },
      //   {
      //     daysOfWeek: [6], // Saturday
      //     startTime: '10:00',
      //     endTime: '14:00'
      //   }
      // ],
    }      

  return (
      <>
        <BookingUpdate
          open={addSidebarOpen}
          pending={bookingPending}
          updatePending={updatePending}
          selectedBooking={getBooking}
          locationsList={locationsList}
          handleOpen={handleAddAppointmentSidebar}
        />
  
        <Card className="shadow-none border-0 mb-0 bg-yellow rounded-0">
          <CardBody className="p-0 relative">
            <Label htmlFor="datePicker">
              <Icon.Calendar
                color="white"
                size={30}
                className="absolute datePicker-icon pointer"
              />
            </Label>

            <div className="calendar-selectors absolute-selectors">
              <SelectField
                header
                wd="100%"
                search={false}
                value={location}
                data={locationsList}
                controlMaxWidth="270px"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  onChangeHandler('location', e)
                  onChangeHandler('room', null)
                }}
                disabled={locationsPending}
                isLoading={locationsPending}
                controlMinWidth={
                  extraLargeScreen ? '230px' : largeScreen ? '180px' : '100%'
                }
                placeholder={locationsPending ? 'Loading...' : 'Locations'}
              />

              {allRoomsDayGrid && (
                <SelectField
                  header
                  wd="100%"
                  value={room}
                  search={false}
                  data={roomsList}
                  controlMaxWidth="270px"
                  disabled={roomsPending}
                  isLoading={roomsPending}
                  // formikError={!!room?.value === ''}
                  onChange={(e) => onChangeHandler('room', e)}
                  controlMinWidth={
                    extraLargeScreen ? '230px' : largeScreen ? '180px' : '100%'
                  }
                  placeholder={
                    location?.value ? 'Select Room' : 'Select Location First'
                  }
                />
              )}
            </div>
  
            <Fragment>
              <FullCalendar {...calendarOptions} />
            </Fragment>
            <Flatpickr
              id="datePicker"
              name="datePicker"
              disabled={view === 'resourceTimeGridDay'}
              className="form-control datePicker-non-visible"
              onChange={onDateChangeHandler}
              options={{
                mode: 'range',
                enableTime: false,
                dateFormat: 'F j, Y'
              }}
            />
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </>
    )
  }

    export default memo(Calendar)
```

Comment: Is this really a [mre] of the specific issue? There seems to be a fair bit of irrelevant stuff in here. Please boil it down to just the code we really need, to understand this problem, so we can see the wood for the trees. Admittedly I'm not a react user so it's harder for me, but I cannot see exactly where your code fetches new data from the API, or updates the calendar events with it.

Comment: @ADyson, I cannot minimize the code because the react developers will not be able to understand the scenario, but what I can tell you is that the code is fetching data from API in getAllBookingsAction, and the events are getting updated via memoization in memoizedEvents and memoizedDurationEvents, so basically I have to render the events conditionally so that if the room in a specific location is not selected then the calendar will render memoizedDurationEvents list, and if the room has been selected then it will show the momeoizedEvents list